# Fetch website data using app scripts in Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fetch, google-sheets-formula

Earlier I asked a question about fetching data with the =IMPORTXML function in Google Sheets. Now I've got that working but I understood that a script could work better for the reliability an usability.

The issue with the present script (see below) is that it only fetch data from one url. I want to import data from multiple url's (every country has its own unique url). I want to fetch multiple data per URL. It all concerns travel advices from the Dutch gouverment to other countries. Within my [**spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb60Nj7Of91eC8hYlmhE1LBDxa0U3SN94KDZmA20Kig/edit?usp=sharing) I've added a column with the unique URL's in A, plain tekst countries in B and the data to fetch in column C, D and E.

**The data I would like to fetch**

- colour-status (Geel, Oranje, Rood) `[can be found within <h3></h3>]`
- mapurl (url of the .png file with the map including travel advices) `[can be found within <paragraph></paragraph>]`
- summary (summary of the present travel advice) `[can be found within <summary></summary>]`

I hope that you can help me to improve the script to make it easier to fetch 'traveladvice' data from the government.

```
function parseXml() {
  
  var url = 'https://opendata.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/v1/sources/nederlandwereldwijd/infotypes/traveladvice/a790e247-8ff8-4aa8-be93-9202ccaa180a';
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  str = xml.split("<paragraphtitle>Veiligheidsrisico’s</paragraphtitle>")[1]
  mySubString = str.match(new RegExp("<summary>" + "(.*)" + "</summary>"))[1];
  
  return mySubString;
}
```

(Script from: Marios, thanks Marios!) And followed by `=parseXml()` within a cell in the spreadsheet to fetch the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use the following three custom functions:

```
function parseXmlSummary(url) {
  
  try{
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  mySubString = xml.match(new RegExp("<summary>" + "(.*)" + "</summary>"))[1];
  return mySubString;
  }
  catch(e){return "";}
}

function parseXmlMapURL(url) {
   
  try{
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  mySubString = "https://"+xml.match(new RegExp("CDATA\\[https://" + "(.*)" + ".png"))[1]+".png";
  return mySubString;
  }
  catch(e){return "";}
}


function parseXmlColours(url) {
  
  try{
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  str = xml.split("<paragraphtitle>Veiligheidsrisico’s</paragraphtitle>")[1]
  var colours = ['Geel', 'Oranje', 'Rood'];
  res_colour = colours.filter(c => str.includes(c))[0];
  return res_colour;
  } 
  catch(e){return "";}

}
```

and then you can call them separately as formulas like that:

- `=parseXmlSummary(A7)`
- `=parseXmlMapURL(A7)`
- `=parseXmlColours(A7)`

Assuming cell **A7** contains the given URL.

For all the other cells below (**A8**, **A9**, ..) you can just drag the formula down as you usually do with other formulas.

Comment: You don't need to parse the xml if you're not using xpath. Also, you should probably use xpath for this.

Comment: @pguardiario True, but in his previous question he had Xml. So I just followed up on his previous question. But thanks for the information. xpath just provides longer formulas.

Comment: @pguardiario thanks, I removed it. I didn't understand initially your comment. Thanks again.